# C# magic double value parse

Tags: double, xmlserializer

Currently I am working with numbers with high precisions in complex calculations.
Some of results and source data should be stored in serialized form. 
Everything was good till I get **magic** double value: **0.00000060912702792848**.

Writing that value to string (that what XmlWriter does):

```
s = d.ToString("R", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

gives expected result **6.0912702792848E-07**.

But magic starts when I try to get double value back (the way how XmlReader works):

```
d=double.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Float,  NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Converted back value is 0.00000060912702792848005 with **005** extra digits at the end.

It looks like special combination of numbers that gives such result. 
What do I miss?

Environment: Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit.

Comment: I presume you're aware that floating-point numbers are not meant to be exact?

Comment: Yes, that`s I know. And I whouldn`t wonder if I get a deviation on mathematical operation with doubles. But I am surprised why I get the other number after converting double from string and from where those extra numbers come.

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly an answer to your question, if you want to get rid of the extra decimals at the end, you may use:

```
s = d.ToString("G20", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Comment: I know ways how to hack it. My question was why it happens exactly on that number. And from where those magic digits after converting come.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN documentation for the Roundtrip (R) Format Specifier contains the following note:

> In some cases, Double values formatted with the "R" standard numeric
>   format string do not successfully round-trip if compiled using the
>   /platform:x64 or /platform:anycpu switches and run on 64-bit systems.
>   To work around this problem, you can format Double values by using the
>   "G17" standard numeric format string. The following example uses the
>   "R" format string with a Double value that does not round-trip
>   successfully, and also uses the "G17" format string to successfully
>   round-trip the original value.
>   ([Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx))

I could reproduce your problem when setting the platform to AnyCpu und disabling the `prefer 32 bit` flag in the project settings. When enabling the `prefer 32 bit` flag, the parsed double matches the original, serialized value.
As the documentation states, you can use the G17 format string to receive the expected values.